# Diferencias entre file_get_contents() y curl

Tags: php, curl

Estoy haciedo un `script` para obtener contenido desde una url y he encontrado  [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/819195/8081356), [aqui](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/847965/How-to-get-Html-Source-Code-of-A-url-in-Php) y [aqui](https://www.caveofprogramming.com/php-tutorial/php-get-url-download-html-pages-or-get-the-page-url-in-php.html) que se puede hacer con `curl` y con `file_gets_contents()`, pero no tengo del todo claro dos cosas:

- ¿Qué diferencias hay entre las dos?
- ¿Cuál es la mas apropiada para obtener `html` desde una url para luego analizar el `html`?

El código que he usado es este:

**file_get_contents**

```
$html = file_get_contents($urlFlujo, false, $context);
```

**curl**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Realizan la misma función que es obtener un html a partir de una url, pero no tengo claro que funcionen de la misma forma o sirvan exactamente para lo mismo.

Pido solo datos empíricos y demostrables de qué forma es la más apropiada (menor tiempo de ejecución, menor consumo de recursos, etc.) para mi caso.

Comment: ¿Qué has investigado? ¿Qué no has entendido al respecto? Es importante indicar esfuerzo, máxime cuando llevas tantas preguntas y tiempo en el sitio. ¡Debes ser un referente de cómo preguntar!

Comment: No creo que añadir tres enlaces aporte demasiado. La cosa es: ¿qué has probado? ¿qué te ha funcionado? ¿qué no? Si lo que pretendes es crear una pregunta canónica, puede serte útil leer [¿Es válido realizar preguntas sin mostrar esfuerzo si no es para poner una respuesta propia al mismo tiempo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2156/83). Resumiéndolo, si quieres crear contenido en base a preguntas genéricas, lo que la comunidad agradecería es que contestaras tú mismo. De lo contrario no queda clara la finalidad de la pregunta.

Comment: ¿Como voy yo a contestar si no se la respuesta? Si pregunto será por algo, las preguntas estan claras. He probado las dos, me ha funcionado pero quiero saber que diferencias hay y cual es la mas apropiado para el uso que le voy a dar @fedorqui

Comment: El primer enlace que muestras lo explica muy bien. ¿Qué no te quedó claro al respecto? Nótese que aquí se responde _ayudando_ a comer, no dando de comer.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el motivo por el que se intenta cerrar esta pregunta? No lo entiendo...

Comment: Yo tampoco lo se, La pregunta está bien clara, no son opiniones, son datos tecnicos

Comment: No tienes por qué poner una edicion en mayusculas... asi no ganas respeto y pierdo todo interés en leer tu pregunta. Por cierto, tienes dos votos de reapertura. Paciencia

Comment: Tienes razón, yalo he corregido @lois6b uno de los votos es mio, asi que de poco sirve si faltan 3...

Comment: Pides una respuesta que contenga datos técnicos (menos consumo, tiempo de ejecución, etc.) pero has marcado como buena una respuesta que aunque es buena, no contiene nada de lo que pides. Creo que hasta que no tengamos el centro de documentación este tipo de preguntas no aportan, pero es mi humilde opinión que conste.

Comment: Comprendo que a algunos no les guste que compare esta comunidad con su homóloga en inglés. Pero es que en casos como este es inevitable. Invito a que vean la acogida de una pregunta similar a esta en aquella comunidad (ver enlace de mi respuesta). Alguno podrá decir _es que no somos ellos_. Claro que no, somos más pobres que ellos en contenido y en visión y quizá por eso, en parte, existe poco contenido bueno para los programadores hispanohablantes. Yo he visto incluso preguntas bastante malas, a mi juicio, relanzadas por la comunidad , mientras que vamos cerrando preguntas como esta.

Comment: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2237/45237 @A.Cedano Gracias

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En pocas palabras:

#### [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php)

Es un simple *destornillador*. Ideal para simples solicitudes GET donde el encabezado, método de solicitud HTTP, tiempo de espera, cookies, redirecciones y otras cosas más complejas no importan.

También se pueden usar para peticiones POST, pero habría que crear un contexto para ello ([Ver esta contribución en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php#108309)).

Es menos seguro que `cURL` y por eso viene desactivado por defecto en muchos entornos PHP.

#### [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php)

Es mucho más potente y para usos más avanzados.

`cURL`  es probablemente la librería de HTTP más ampliamente utilizada en el mundo de la programación. Originalmente fue codificado utilizando lenguaje C, y luego fue portado a muchos otros lenguajes.

cURL puede manejar manipulaciones HTTP complicadas de manera elegante, como solicitudes HTTP asíncronas, informes de progreso, etc.

El único problema de cURL es que requiere algún tiempo, varias horas al menos, para familiarizarse con sus funciones y estilo de codificación.

Pero al ser una librería tan usada, la documentación y ejemplos de código en la red son abundantes.

Como ejemplo, sólo basta con ver la amplia documentación para `cURL` en el Manual de PHP (enlace de más arriba).

---

#### ¿Cuál es más rápido?

Todas las pruebas que he leído hasta ahora indican que `cURL` es más rápido.

El siguiente gráfico es el producto de una prueba entre diferentes métodos, publicada por Philip Norton en ***[Quickest Way To Download A Web Page With PHP](http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/quickest-way-download-web-page-php)***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ver también:

- [PHP cURL vs file_get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064995) en Stackoverflow en inglés.
- [Comparison of the HTTP libs in PHP: file_get_contents vs. cURL vs. PECL_HTTP](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1019822/Comparison-of-the-HTTP-libs-in-PHP-file-get-conten)

Comment: file_get_contents() también puede hacer peticiones POST, PUT, etc. Aunque tu descripción no dice que no pueda hacer, pudiera parecer que se limita únicamente al método GET.

Comment: @Muriano yaaaa, no he dicho que no, pero hay que crear un contexto para ello. Ver [esta contribución del Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php#108309). Y... no por casualidad se llama `file_`**`get`**`_contents()`. Hay que dejarle campo a la investigación del OP, en los enlaces de cada uno ya hay bastante material... :)

Answer (score 1):

Realmente sirven para lo mismo, sólo que `file_gets_contents` va de serie en PHP, y `curl` es un módulo que hay que instalar y activar en la configuración de PHP.

`curl` tiene muchas más opciones, más sencillas de utilizar y hay muchos más ejemplos en internet.

Con `file_get_contents` tienes funciones parecidas a `curl`, pero tienes que montarte un contexto, con streams y otras cosas que complican bastante, por lo menos al principio.

De todas formas la principal y más importante diferencia es que la función `file`, la cual es utilizada por `file_get_contents`, **puede estar bloqueada en algunos servidors web compartidos de algunos hostings**, ya que ciertos usos de la misma pueden ser un problema de seguridad. En caso de estar bloqueada tendrás que utilizar `curl` por obligación.