# Fallo de conexión al API de stackoverflow.com

Tags: php, json, api

Estoy intentando conectarme al API de stackoverflow con este código:

```
$request='https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/245813/revisions?site=es.stackoverflow';
$r=json_decode(file_get_contents($request));
print_r($r);
```

Pero, en vez de recibir este JSON:

```
{"items":[{"user":{"reputation":646,"user_id":119615,"user_type":"registered","profile_image":"https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHjNA.jpg?s=128&g=1","display_name":"David","link":"https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/119615/david"},"set_community_wiki":false,"is_rollback":false,"creation_date":1552603063,"post_id":245813,"post_type":"question","revision_type":"single_user","revision_number":2,"comment":"El c&#243;digo PHP no se ejecuta en SO","revision_guid":"E6C4E505-3F15-4761-95A4-039F60526EFB"},{"tags":["php","mysql","post"],"user":{"reputation":17,"user_id":113447,"user_type":"registered","profile_image":"https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca122f2249fa55f5e3e12156c9c4e2fd?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG","display_name":"jonathan","link":"https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/113447/jonathan"},"set_community_wiki":false,"is_rollback":false,"creation_date":1552594218,"post_id":245813,"post_type":"question","revision_type":"single_user","revision_number":1,"title":"consulta Mysql con datos enviados por POST","revision_guid":"1828F694-7C46-4663-A739-E987405A7542"}],"has_more":false,"quota_max":300,"quota_remaining":261}
```

Recibo algo así:

```
��S�n�0��I}
��hʺd}Y�{�&�!NS�$����.$�:�/��7����9��H9�X�~;��J��#2��pJ�(�O�B�
�b�p�.��I�Bw���Fh�:�KU�L5���:���Z'�ǩj��Ls�����b���v��쪚c�/��jq�Z���N
��j_�I{��;i�Z�G���
��b�9���~%+����#�qDNTòQ���9ا����7��_Q�E����2b'�8��|r�   )   �I)+��$&��<ɩ$eqIG1WX�r�^�����Q��V��h�0-���e���%�����N�z�7l_C,�{���
m!&;%
8t�x���oD��l���ה����_�Q�/�YLC��%����5���O�v"k��Fa�|7��� ���O9�5}Y
```

He indagado en https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication
y en http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php pero no consigo dar con el fallo

Comment: Pon ante todo este encabezado: `header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");`   y me parece que no es necesario usar `file_get_contents`, la API ya devuelve un JSON.

Comment: Nada, qué va, he probado ambas cosas y no hay forma...

Comment: El `header` se pone para definir el tipo de **salida** que quieres en el **script**, no tiene nada que ver con el formato de entrada de los datos, ni usando `cURL` ni usando `file_get_contents` ni ninguna otra función de adquisición de datos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No existe fallo de conexión como tal, ya que la API responde.

El "problema" es la respuesta de la API, que es una cadena "comprimida"

Para descomprimir una cadena comprimida debes utilizar [gzinflate()](http://php.net/gzinflate)

```
<?php

$request='https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/245813/revisions?site=es.stackoverflow';
$r=file_get_contents($request);

var_dump(gzinflate(substr($r,10)));


?>
```

Como bien dice @fly :

> gzinflate devuelve un string, por lo cual debes hacer un
>   json_decode(gzinflate(substr($r,10))) para obtener un json como el de
>   la respuesta.

Comment: Aún así hay que hacer un `json_decode(gzinflate(substr($r,10, -8)))` pues [gzinflate](http://php.net/manual/es/function.gzinflate.php) devuelve un `string`.

Comment: @Fly te cito en la respuesta. (editado) gracias.

Comment: Me permito comentar que [`cURL` es más rápido y más seguro que file_get_contents](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/81570/29967)  y la información se obtendría de forma transparente, sin necesidad de aplicar funciones adicionales a los datos como `gzinflate` y `substr`.

Comment: @A.Cedano claro, mencionar de todas maneras que file_get_contents no es un modulo aparte como lo es cURL.

Comment: En efecto, [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.file-get-contents.php)  es una función nativa de PHP, mientras que [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/es/book.curl.php) es  una biblioteca aparte, pero totalmente integrada a PHP y ampliamente usada. Por cierto, [`gzinflate`](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.zlib.php) tampoco es nativa de PHP, pertenece a una biblioteca aparte (`Zlib`).

Answer (score 2):

A mi me funciona usando `cURL`. Cuando hay problemas de codificación se le puede pasar esta opción en la configuración: `CURLOPT_ENCODING=>""` en vez de `utf-8`.

```
$request='https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/posts/245813/revisions?site=es.stackoverflow';
$ch = curl_init($request);
$options=array( CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>TRUE, 
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST=>"GET", 
                CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT=>TRUE,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING=>"");
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
$mJson=json_decode($response);
var_dump($mJson);
if(curl_errno($ch))
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

**Salida:**

```
object(stdClass)#1 (4) {
  ["items"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (10) {
      ["user"]=>
      object(stdClass)#3 (6) {
        ["reputation"]=>
        int(686)
        ["user_id"]=>
        int(119615)
        ["user_type"]=>
        string(10) "registered"
        ["profile_image"]=>
        string(45) "https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHjNA.jpg?s=128&g=1"
        ["display_name"]=>
        string(5) "David"
        ["link"]=>
        string(47) "https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/119615/david"
      }
      ["set_community_wiki"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["is_rollback"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["creation_date"]=>
      int(1552603063)
      ["post_id"]=>
      int(245813)
      ["post_type"]=>
      string(8) "question"
      ["revision_type"]=>
      string(11) "single_user"
      ["revision_number"]=>
      int(2)
      ["comment"]=>
      string(38) "El c&#243;digo PHP no se ejecuta en SO"
      ["revision_guid"]=>
      string(36) "E6C4E505-3F15-4761-95A4-039F60526EFB"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(stdClass)#4 (11) {
      ["tags"]=>
      array(3) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "php"
        [1]=>
        string(5) "mysql"
        [2]=>
        string(4) "post"
      }
      ["user"]=>
      object(stdClass)#5 (6) {
        ["reputation"]=>
        int(17)
        ["user_id"]=>
        int(113447)
        ["user_type"]=>
        string(10) "registered"
        ["profile_image"]=>
        string(87) "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ca122f2249fa55f5e3e12156c9c4e2fd?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"
        ["display_name"]=>
        string(8) "jonathan"
        ["link"]=>
        string(50) "https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/113447/jonathan"
      }
      ["set_community_wiki"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["is_rollback"]=>
      bool(false)
      ["creation_date"]=>
      int(1552594218)
      ["post_id"]=>
      int(245813)
      ["post_type"]=>
      string(8) "question"
      ["revision_type"]=>
      string(11) "single_user"
      ["revision_number"]=>
      int(1)
      ["title"]=>
      string(42) "consulta Mysql con datos enviados por POST"
      ["revision_guid"]=>
      string(36) "1828F694-7C46-4663-A739-E987405A7542"
    }
  }
  ["has_more"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["quota_max"]=>
  int(300)
  ["quota_remaining"]=>
  int(283)
}
```

Comment: El `header` se pone para definir el tipo de **salida** que quieres en el **script**, no tiene nada que ver con el formato de entrada de los datos, ni usando `cURL` ni usando `file_get_contents` ni ninguna otra función de adquisición de datos.

Comment: @Fly tienes toda la razón. Gracias por la aclaración. Saludos.