# PHP Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: php

Estoy intentando descargar una imagen en un servidor remoto usando este código.

```
// Imagen de ejemplo
$imageURL = 'https://keyprint.keystoneindustries.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/cast-on-model.png';
$content = @file_get_contents($imageURL);
// mas código....
```

El error que obtengo es:

> Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Intente aplicar estas soluciones:

- [`"verify_peer_name"=>false`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26151993/3791844)
- [`"verify_peer_name"=>true` + `'cafile' => '/path/to/bundle/cacert.pem'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28701786/3791844)

Pero continuo obteniendo el mismo resultado.

¿Qué puedo hacer para poder obtener esa imagen por ejemplo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que el problema se da porque el servidor bloquea peticiones que no provienen de un navegador y bastaría con crear un [contexto de flujo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.stream-context-create.php) donde se deshabilite la verificación de certificado SSL y se agreguen encabezados para simular que es un navegador el que realiza la petición:

```
$context = stream_context_create([
    // Deshabilitar verificación de certificado
    "ssl" => [
        "verify_peer" => false,
        "verify_peer_name" => false,
    ],
    // Simular petición como navegador
    "http" => [
        'timeout' => 60,
        'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.9) Gecko/20071025 Firefox/3.0.0.1'
    ]
]);
$imageURL = 'https://keyprint.keystoneindustries.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/cast-on-model.png';
$content = file_get_contents($imageURL, 0, $context);
var_dump($content); // Voilà!
```

Ejemplo del resultado:

```
E:\***\***-test.php:31:string '�PNG


���
IHDR��������++�� �IDATx��w�n�]�{�j_���s��*��h�`��X��A��c�n
```

### Sin desactivar verificación de certificados

Dependiendo del servidor a donde se enviará la petición, puedes omitir la parte de deshabilitar verificación de certificado y solo simular la petición desde un navegador:

```
$context = stream_context_create([
    // Simular petición como navegador
    "http" => [
        'timeout' => 60,
        'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.9) Gecko/20071025 Firefox/3.0.0.1'
    ]
]);
$imageURL = 'https://keyprint.keystoneindustries.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/cast-on-model.png';
$content = file_get_contents($imageURL, 0, $context);
var_dump($content); // Voilà!
```

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que uses cURL. Es más potente y fácil de configurar, y podrás capturar más fácilmente los errores.

Puede que tu error se resuelva agregado el parámetro: `CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION`  adecuado.

Te muestro una función donde implementaremos cURL (lo escribí en forma de función por si quieres reutilizarlo en otros contextos).

```
function file_get_contents_ssl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 3000); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10000); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    if(!$result)
    {
        # Para depurar, cámbialo luego por otro tipo de manejo de errores
        var_dump(curl_error($ch));
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

Y para llamar a la función en tu contexto:

```
$imageURL = 'https://keyprint.keystoneindustries.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/cast-on-model.png';
$content = file_get_contents_ssl($imageURL);
var_dump($content);
```

En mi caso al hacer esto el error que indicas en la pregunta ha desaparecido, aunque está dando ahora otro tipo de error:

> "OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection reset by peer, errno 104"

En tu contexto creo que se resolvería añadiendo a la petición cURL otros elementos de los que dispones para esa conexión, como el archivo de certificado u otras cabeceras que sean requeridas por ese sitio para darte acceso a sus recursos. Si no funciona, puede que el sitio esté protegiendo sus recursos y deberías contactar con ellos para que te indiquen cómo debes configurar tu petición.

Comment: Esta aproximación es buena, tal vez solo falta enviar [encabezado](https://www.php.net/manual/es/context.curl.php#context.curl.header) u otra opción como `user-agent` para que funcione correctamente. Por otra parte, tengo mis dudas en cuanto a _"cURL es más potente y fácil de configurar"_.

Comment: @Triby [aquí se abordó el tema con un poco más de profundidad](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/81570/29967), no obstante, si estoy en un error agradezco cualquier fuente/información que sea de ayuda para rectificar..

Comment: En todo caso, **tiene mejor rendimiento**, pero dudo que sea más _"potente"_, porque con `file_get_contents()` puedes hacer lo mismo y, definitivamente NO es _"más fácil de configurar"_, requieres inicializar, establecer cada opción y, finalmente, ejecutar y cerrar; mientras que con `file_get_contents()` puedes crear un contexto a partir de un arreglo.

Comment: @Triby en `file_get_contents()` tienes que hacer algo parecido si necesitas mandar cabeceras. Con cURL puedes pasar un array con todas las configuraciones, no es obligatorio pasarlas una por una y el manejo de errores es más intuitivo. Yo particularmente prefiero cURL, pero quizá sea solo eso, una cuestión de preferencias.

Comment: Efectivamente, `cURL` se puede [configurar con un arreglo](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-setopt-array.php), mucho más _"verboso"_ que el de un contexto de flujo. Coincido plenamente con la última parte de tu comentario: es solo una cuestión de preferencias.

Comment: Finalmente, siempre es bueno dar crédito a la [fuente original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66195974/2412893).

Comment: @Triby NO necesariamente más verboso, puedes crear un array al estilo de las cabeceras tradicionales, con la notación: `"Parametro :  valor"`, ([ver un ejemplo aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15134580/5587982)). En cuanto a la fuente original, no es exactamente ese el problema resuelto allí. Lo definitivo en cuanto a la respuesta que doy aquí es agregar la cabecera `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);` e incluyo un manejo de errores en la función.