# cURL solo funciona en localhost y en cloud no funciona

Tags: php, curl

Estoy intentado obtener datos de url mediante cURL. logre obtener conexito en local pero cuando subo a mi host no funciona. con el var_dum($resp), me arroja el siguiente error `/home/xxxxxy/public_html/mysite.com/curl.php:33:boolean false`
Pd. probé con postman online obtener los datos mediante meto POST del url me arroja el siguinete mensaje. `Cloud Agent Error: Request is taking longer than 30 seconds to fulfill`, pero si me arroja los datos con el postman del escritorio.
Adicional con curl_error(); me arroja el siguiente error `Error:Failed to connect to dominio.com port 8080: Connection refused`

cURL.php

```
<?php

$url = "http://170.80.71.223:8080/registro?&cmb_tipo=1";

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$headers = array(
   "Accept: application/json",
   "Content-Type: application/json",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$data = <<<DATA
{
  "Id": 78912,
  "Customer": "Jason Sweet",
  "Quantity": 1,
  "Price": 18.00
}
DATA;

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

//for debug only!
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);
```

Comment: Pues depende. Si yo pruebo esa URL, también me quedo esperando infinito (hasta que mi cliente dice _timeout_ y cancela). ¿Será posible que el servidor al que le haces la petición tenga reglas de los orígenes permitidos y tu servidor en la nube no esté ahí incluído?

Comment: Lo mismo, yo tampoco puedo conectar a esa IP, ni por el puerto 8080 ni por el 80.

Comment: La url que coloco solo es un ejemplo no es a la que estoy apuntando, Posiblemente tenga algún firewall, como dije anteriormente probé de varios de postman online y también de reqbin con el metodo POST, que son obviamente diferentes servidores y tampoco retornan la petición, solo  en local me funciona.

Comment: Para saber lo que está pasando usa [curl_error()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.curl-error.php) y, de ser necesario, edita la pregunta para agregar el mensaje de error.

Comment: @Triby. Me arroja el siguiente error 
Error:Failed to connect to dominio.com port 8080: Connection refused

Comment: @wcs8277, el servidor está rechazando la conexión, probablemente por CORS, habría que ver si es necesario agregar encabezados para simular que la petición es de un navegador.

Comment: @Triby . gracias por su respuesta no entiendo mucho el tema de CORS, me podrías detallar un poquito mas :)

Comment: No sé si [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/476308/54039) te pueda servir de algo.